# How do I remove the white background and title of my pop up window?

Tags: android

I need to remove  the white background and the blue panel

[image: img]

Comment: This is the recents screen? The blue bar is the Toolbar of your app and the white background is your actual app

Comment: how can I remove the toolbar

Comment: I don't know what you're asking unless you add your code to the question

Comment: dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); => add this line before  dialog.setContentView();

Answer (score 0):

**TWO way to remove toolbar**

In your activity.java

**1**、`extends Activity` is instead of `extends AppCompatActivity`

**2**、still use `extends AppCompatActivity`and put getSupportActionBar().hide(); in your onCreate method.

**remove the white backgroud**  have three way

**1**、Try to adjust your xml

**2**、put android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" in your AndroidManifest

**3**、set alpha to your activity v.getBackground().setAlpha(0);

//v is Id of your activity View v = findViewById(R.id.activity);